# Changing a connected rigid body in unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so imagine a replica of angry birds, I’ve made a hook (a circle that I’ve made transparent), and I’ve made the movement I want, but now, I was to let’s say, attach my SpringJoint2D  to a new hook when I trigger it (OnTriggerEnter), so like I’m on an old hook or anchor point, and I release my ball (like a bird flying) and I want to go through another hook/anchor point, and get the ability to shoot again

heres my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
        public Rigidbody2D rb;
        bool isPressed =  false;
        public float releaseTime = .10f;
    void Update()
    {
        if(isPressed)
        {
            rb.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
    }



    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isPressed = true;
        rb.isKinematic = true;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isPressed = false;
        rb.isKinematic = false;

        StartCoroutine(Release());
    }

    IEnumerator Release()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(releaseTime);
        
        GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>().enabled = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Hook"))
        {
            GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>().enabled = true;
            GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>().ConnectedRigidBody = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        }
    }
}
```

so what i want is
[image: Visual Bad Represintation]

Comment: Haven't toyed with joints yet, but I would assume you need some code to set the Transform position back to its original position after it's released? Have an "empty" GameObject in the scene to mark that position, so you can easily get the correct initial coordinates without hard-coding them.

Comment: yeah that’s what the hook is, and once I release, I turn the spring joint off, but when it enters a body that has the tag hook, it turns back on, still trying to figure out how to change the hook rigid body to the one I collided with

Comment: Could the collision detection be conditional on the spring joint being active?

Comment: I don’t think so, since I’m only turning off the joint (the component), and not the whole game object.

Comment: Wish I could help more, I'm still only playing with the 2D stuff and trying to get my little Mario to actually jump like a Mario  ...I might not be understanding exactly what's going on here but still I would think there'd be a way to slip a bit of code in the collision detection (OnTriggerEnter) to check the state of the joint and prevent it from turning back on. Hmm...

Comment: The problem isn’t it turning back, it actually works how I want it to, but, I want to after I release the ball and it flings, to like attach to a different hook so that you can gain momentum again

Comment: I think it could help visual others better understand the problem if you added screenshots to illustrate, along with the code you have in your collision detection; feel free to [edit] your post!

Comment: there you go, i added a bad drawing and my code if you can figure out the problem. ofcourse the GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>().connectedrigidbody isnt real but i thought it would work